# Cómo poner ejemplos de Código en un blog de Blogger?

Tags: blogger

sé que podrá sonar tonto para ustedes, experimentados y consumados programadores.
La duda que tengo en este momento es si es posible poner este tipo de ejemplos en un blog de Blogguer, y si lo es, cómo se hace?

[image: ejemplo de código en un blog]

no debe ser exactamente igual, me conformo con poder poner ejemplos de código por ejemplo como este:

```
def ejemplo():
    print("Ejemplo de Código en en un blog")
```

Comment: Eso es porque el blog puede intepretar `markdown` , mira este link te  puede  ayudar: https://markdown.es/

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras amigo pero yo uso por ejemplo los tags <pre><code>  tu codigo formateado aqui .. </code></pre>
pero eso depende de tu plantilla Blogger, A veces vienen con un CSS elaborado para pre y code y muestran un cuadro de codigo bonito y a veces no y por eso muestran algo muy basico. Mi plantilla usando pre y code muestra asi el codigo con un pequeño retoque del CSS de la Plantilla.

https://www.mediafire.com/view/mnl7s1ji3c1aov6/Text_block_using_section_tag_directly_in_Blogger_post_.png/file

En tu ejemplo me parece que se muestra Syntax Highlighter que se debe instalar en la Plantilla Blogger para que te muestre asi el codigo en colores.